# Selected build variant changes when Android Studio is restarted

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android app, there are 4 build variants, freeDebug, freeRelease, proDebug, proRelease. I usually use proDebug variant when developing the application.

Sometimes when I start Android Studio, I see that the selected build variant has been changed to freeDebug.

What is the reason for this? Is there any way I can instruct Android Studio to use proDebug by default?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36988145

Comment: which version of the android studio are you using? I have many build variants but this never happened to me.

Comment: Why `freeDebug` is the default for you is because it's the first one alphabetically.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir I use Android Studio 3.3.1. I also didn't have a problem earlier. This problem only occurred recently. Also, it doens't happen after each Android Studio restart. It only happens randomly.